# new Thread(new Runnable)).start() causes NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, sockets

I googled it and StackoverFlow but there's not much information I can use.

And most of the answers suggest to use thread, don't open socket in main thread.

Anyway my code like this

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
private Socket socket;

private static ObjectOutputStream oos;

public Client() {
    mPauseLock = new Object();
    mPaused = false;
    mFinished = false;
    try {
        socket = new Socket("168.131.148.50", 5001);
        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i < MsgQueue.getSize(); i++) {
            try {
                oos.writeObject(MsgQueue.get(i));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
}
```

and in **MainActivity** 
    `new Thread(new Client()).start();`

But still I get **NetworkOnMainThreadExcpetion**..

Can anybody tell me solution please?

Answer (score 1):

try moving the initialization code in the constructor right before the for loop in run()

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the socket call in the main thread when calling the line "new Client()", you should move all the code related to the socket creation inside the run method, you must know that only the "run" method is executed in the background thread, not the class initialization:

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
private Socket socket;

private static ObjectOutputStream oos;

public Client() {
    mPauseLock = new Object();
    mPaused = false;
    mFinished = false;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket("168.131.148.50", 5001);
        pw = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < MsgQueue.getSize(); i++) {
        try {
            oos.writeObject(MsgQueue.get(i));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

}

You should read more about java before jumping into Android...

Regards!